# How to use detecting tracking for multiple cameras parallel?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, yolo

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--source', type=str, default='inference/images', help='source') 0 for webcam
    parser.set_defaults(download=True)
    
    opt = parser.parse_args()
    with torch.no_grad():
        if opt.update:  # update all models (to fix SourceChangeWarning)
            for opt.weights in ['yolov7.pt']:
                detect()
                strip_optimizer(opt.weights)
        else:
            detect()
```

I run this code like this:

```
python detect_and_track.py --weights yolo_result.py --source sample_video.py
```

How can I run this for multiple cameras?